Marklogic : cts:parse to run wildcarded/case-insensitive searches with NEAR option
I have a requirement to run the below string wildcarded and case-insensitive search
"overexpression NEAR/1[ordered] predict*"
I am using cts:parse("overexpression NEAR/1[ordered] predict*") and the query generated is :
cts:near-query((
  cts:word-query("overexpression", ("lang=en"), 1), 
  cts:word-query("predict*", ("lang=en"), 1)
), 1, ("ordered"), 1) 

So how can I enable wildcard searches? I mean the query to be formed should be :
cts:near-query((
  cts:word-query("overexpression", ("wildcarded","case-insensitive","lang=en"), 1), 
  cts:word-query("predict*", (""wildcarded","case-insensitive","lang=en"), 1)
), 1, ("ordered"), 1) 

How can I achieve this?

As indicated in the Usage Notes for cts:word-query:

If neither "case-sensitive" nor "case-insensitive" is present, $text is used to determine case sensitivity. If $text contains no uppercase, it specifies "case-insensitive". If $text contains uppercase, it specifies "case-sensitive".
If neither "wildcarded" nor "unwildcarded" is present, the database configuration and $text determine wildcarding. If the database has any wildcard indexes enabled ("three character searches", "two character searches", "one character searches", or "trailing wildcard searches") and if $text contains either of the wildcard characters '?' or '*', it specifies "wildcarded". Otherwise it specifies "unwildcarded".

When the wildcarded and unwildcarded options are not explicitly set, then the presence and absence of a wildcard character (* or ?) will determine whether or not the query is wildcarded.
Similarly, for case-sensitive and case-insensitive - if the query value is lower-case then it will be case-insensitive. If it is UPPERCASE or MixedCase, then it will be case-sensitive, unless you explicitly override and set the case option.
So, cts:word-query("predict*", ("lang=en"), 1) is the equivalent of cts:word-query("predict*", (""wildcarded","case-insensitive","lang=en"), 1), and it doesn't really make sense to specify "wildcarded" for the "overexpression" query, since there are no wildcards.
If you want to override that, and ensure that case-insensitive is applied when mixed or UPPER-CASE values are provided, then you can apply $bindings in the second option to cts:parse() and supply your own function that produces the cts:word-query with your explicit options:
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $bindings := map:new() 
    => map:with("", 
         function($operator, $values, $options) {
           cts:word-query($values, ('wildcarded', 'case-insensitive'), 1)
         })
return
  cts:parse("overexpression NEAR/1[ordered] predict*", $bindings)

Which produces:
cts:near-query((
    cts:word-query("overexpression", ("case-insensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), 
    cts:word-query("predict*", ("case-insensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1)
  ), 1, ("ordered"), 1)

For more information, see Customizing Naked Term Handling With Bindings

thanks for the detail explanation.But my search terms could have UPPERCASE or Mixed Case so, I override the case option

Oh, I see - so you are trying to override and ensure that it's case-insensitive search when the values may be mixed or upper.

Can you help with that?

I had updated my answer to show how you can apply bindings to customize the options applied.

Can we achieve the same in search:search ? as we need to create the facets also. search string would still be same "overexpression NEAR/1[ordered] predict*" .I know how to use  options for wildcard and case-insensitive search, but NEAR/1 [ordered/unordered] . How to use these? Near query could be ordered or unordered.If not then how to use faceted search in cts:parse?
